# UIView setNeedsDisplay calling the CALayer's setNeedsDisplay?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

It seems that calling `[self setNeedsDisplay]` on a UIView does not result in a
`[self.layer setNeedsDisplay]`. Is it alright if I override `setNeedsDisplay` as follows:

```
- (void)setNeedsDisplay {
  [super setNeedsDisplay];
  [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Will this get me into trouble? Perhaps there is a better way?
Thank You

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: I would like to call `[myView setNeedsDisplay]` method without having to also call `[myView.layer setNeedsDisplay]`. I set up an elaborate CALayer hierarchy within my UIView subclass.

Comment: Why do you need to call `[CALayer setNeedsDisplay]`? Calling `[UIView setNeedsDisplay]` will cause it to trigger its `-drawRect:` at the end of the run loop. What else are you trying to do?

Comment: Kevin, because drawRect: does not update the CALayers. Are you saying that it is supposed to and I am not seeing intended behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

I posted this as a comment to another answer, but this may be helpful to other people.

A UIView only calls `setNeedsDisplay` on its underlying CALayer when `drawRect:` is implemented (even if the method is empty and does nothing). This tells UIView's `setNeedsDisplay` that its layer also has some drawing to be done.

Another way to get the layer's `setNeedsDisplay` to be called automatically is to set the layer's flag `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange` to true, which will trigger a `setNeedsDisplay` whenever the view's bounds change (which automatically changes the layer's bounds). But to answer your questions, what you're doing is fine if you didn't override `drawRect:`, otherwise it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it would get you into trouble. `setNeedsDisplay` / `setNeedsLayout` just flag that the view/layer needs to be displayed / laid out. It'll do the drawing next time around the run loop.

I'm fairly surprised though that calling it on the view doesn't cause it to happen on the layer, because after all a `UIView` and its associated `CALayer` are quite tightly integrated.

So overall, yeh if you're finding it's not working for you by just calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the view then go for your solution. I don't see how it can harm anything.

Comment: A UIView only calls setNeedsDisplay on its underlying CALayer when drawRect: is implemented (even if the method is empty and does nothing). This tells UIView's setNeedsDisplay that its layer also has some drawing to be done. Another way to get the layer's setNeedsDisplay to be called automatically is to set the layer's flag needsDisplayOnBoundsChange to true, which will trigger a setNeedsDisplay whenever the view's bounds change (which automatically changes the layer's bounds). But to answer your questions, what you're doing is fine if you didn't override drawRect:, otherwise it's redundant.